# Swift 3 UILabel, how to word wrap after changing text

Tags: ios, swift3, uilabel

I have a UILabel which has been created programmatically and want to set the text property dynamically after its creation. I can word wrap it during init but not subsequently. After the title label text is changed it keeps one line, regardless of whether I set the number of lines to 2 or 0 and word wrap or not. After I change the title I want it to occupy 2 lines and the text is easily long enough for this to happen but it does not.

```
let titleLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.backgroundColor = .clear
    label.layer.masksToBounds = true
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
    label.textColor = .white
    return label
}()

var titleLabelText: String? {
    didSet {
        titleLabel.text = titleLabelText
        titleLabel.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

then later...

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        titleLabelText = "some string which needs word wrapping"

}
```

---

```
    titleLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40.0).isActive = true
    titleLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: screenWidth - 90).isActive = true
```

---

Font size is `UIFont(name: "Muli", size: 12)`
Here is how I load my label in `viewDidLoad()` but the label.text is applied in `viewDidAppear()`

```
let headerStackView: UIStackView = {
  let headerArray = [welcomeLabel]
  let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: headerArray)
```

Comment: translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints should be true if you are not using autolayout constraints, if yes try updating the constraints in didSet i.e, view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()

Comment: `label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` is required as I do everything in code without a storyboard. Your suggestion resulted in my anchors being invalidated and a blank view.

Comment: can you please explain how you are adding the label in view, in the above code it is not clear whether you create constraints or add frame programmatically

Comment: if you add constraints programmatically, set titleLabelText in viewDidLayoutSubViews() or viewDidAppear()

Comment: I don't use frames and didSet is at the class level.

Comment: I guess I should use a protocol for this.

Comment: How are you adding the label on your uiview ? Update your code pls

Comment: In a function called in didLoad(). I moved it to didlAppear() but it made no difference.

Comment: did you check `sizeToFit()` ?

Comment: Yes, it didn't help.

Comment: `the text is easily long enough for this to happen` - stupid question, did you check with longer text? Even ridiculously longer - say 10 times longer, than what you want to put there,

Comment: It's a title label in the nav bar and has buttons left and right. How could increasing the label width help as a shorter label should force it to wrap? It works on SE but not a bigger phone (in the simulator)

Comment: if it works on SE then it should also work on other device too...its not working may be because your text size is not enough to wrap for bigger device.

Comment: It has dots at the end so definitely long enough. I know the etxt size is too long even for 2 lines.

Comment: Could you please show us how your `screenWidth` is calculated? Is it `UIScreen.main.bounds.width` or are you using `self.view.bounds.width`?

Comment: can you able put your sample code somewhere and share with me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set your label to display multiple line..Remember your label must have enough height that can hold your text to be display multiple line.

Try to increase height of your label, Check width is proper and then check with your code.

Comment: I did this but it didn't help. The label size should eb adequate and I have edited my question to show the label size.

Comment: @markhorrocks can you log label size and font size in console and comment here?

Comment: size of text (56.712890625, 17.689453125)
size of label (345.0, 74.0), called in ViewDidLoad()

Comment: @markhorrocks size of text (56.712890625, 17.689453125) is your font size? which font style you have used? Also tell me how you are adding this label to your view?

Comment: Not only it should have enought height, its width has to be limited too.

Comment: It is, you can see this by the anchors.

Answer (score 0):

If your text gets increases decrease the font size, it will automatically show complete text in your label.

and set the label line space to 0 and allow word wrap property true

Answer (score 0):

[image: select your label and try this one]

select your label and try this one

Answer (score -2):

AFAIK You need to add it as attributedText, then create an NSAttributedString, with your string and attributes.

```
    let paragraphStyleWithWordWrapping = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyleWithWordWrapping.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    let attributedString = NSAttributedString(myString, [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyleWithWordWrapping])
     label.attributedText = attributedString
```